# angularJs isArray: false or true

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I try to get data from database by spring rest and AngularJS but I get this 
error: when make isArray : true

```
"Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected
  response to contain an array but got an object
```

and when try to solve this error by make

```
 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false}
```

I get this error

```
[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

this is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/assets",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<Asset> getAll() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Assets");
    List<Asset> assets=assetService.getAllOrderByIdDesc();
    return assetService.getAllOrderByIdDesc();
}
```

rout.js

```
 adapApp
   .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider
       , USER_ROLES) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/asset', {
                templateUrl: 'views/assets.html',
                controller: 'AssetController',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedAsset: ['Asset', function (Asset) {
                        return Asset.query().$promise;
                    }]
                },
                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })
    });
```

service.js

```
adapApp.factory('Asset', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('app/rest/assets/:id', {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false},
        'get': { method: 'GET'}
    });
 });
```

Controller

```
adapApp.controller('AssetController', function ($scope, resolvedAsset
      , Asset ) {
$scope.assets = resolvedAsset;
});
```

html page

```
<tr ng-repeat="asset in assets">
                    <td>{{asset.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.assetName}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.locations[0]}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.airport.iatacode}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.lastupdateUserid}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.lastupdateDateTime}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.domainName}}</td>
                    <td>
 <tr>
```

Comment: I think that `query` and `get` both default to `isArray: false`, so you currently have no method that has `isArray: true`

Comment: I use query method  in rout.js not get method

Comment: I seems no problem with the code above. If the error is about '$digest', do you use something like '$digest.$apply' in you code?